# Powershell script to find values in a variable starting with special characters

Tags: powershell

I am new in powershell script trying to find some values in a variable which are not starting with some predefined values. I got variable output in json format, I want to find all the output values which are not starting with special strings ($data). If you see below code $devenv gives a json output containing all the values. $data has some predefined strings, so whatever values $devenv json not starting with $data strings should be displayed.

```
$devVars = az pipelines variable-group list -o json --group-name DEV --query "[0].variables | keys(@)" | ConvertFrom-Json | Sort-Object
Write-Host $devVars
$data = 'CS_','USR_','PWD_','LP_','PRT_','SB_','SP_','VAL_','URL_'
```

Comment: Can you show us the json?

Comment: few values:- CS_AD_Entities_Connection_USR_PWD CS_AD_Entities_USR_PWD CS_Azure_Blob_Storage_ReferenceData_ARINC

Comment: @ashishmishra - can you post the raw *json* returned by the ```az pipelines``` command (without the ```ConvertFrom-Json```)? Without knowing the structure of the json it’s impossible to offer any help with filtering the data.

Comment: Some Output without ConvertFrom-Json --
 "Azure:ServiceBus:Queue",   "CS_AD_Entities_Connection_USR_PWD",   "CS_AD_Entities_USR_PWD",   "CS_Azure_Blob_Storage_ReferenceData_ARINC424",   "CS_Azure_HangFire_Bus",   "CS_Blob_Azure_USR_PWD",   "CS_Blob_CountryWorldAware_USR_PWD",   "CS_Blob_GeographicWorldAware_USR_PWD",   "CS_Blob_WorldAware_USR_PWD",   "CS_Feasibility_ASB_PWD",   "CS_Feasibility_Blob_Storage_PWD",  "PWD_RABBIT_MQ_FILING_PASSWORD",   "PWD_RABBIT_MQ_PASSWORD",   "PWD_RabbitMQ_Alerts", "SP_Degree_image",   "SP_Latlong_image",   "SP_RA_PDF",   "SP_RA_Reports_PDF"

Comment: @mclayton Does this make sense?

Comment: @Theo Do you need more input?

Comment: @AshishMishra - that's not json, so let me rephrase...  can you please just run the command ```az pipelines variable-group list -o json --group-name DEV --query "[0].variables | keys(@)"``` at the command line manually and add the output **to your question** (i.e. not as a comment), and remember to replace any sensitive data with something like "****"

Comment: @mclayton I ran your command output is still same. Please not its a library. Updating question.

Comment: Then it is not JSON.. looking at the image I can't make out what it should be.. Can you capture what @mclayton asked in a variable and do a `.GetType().FullName` on it?

Comment: @Theo - hopefully the OP can confirm, but  I think the ```-o json``` is being ignored by this specific ```az``` command. Filling in the gaps, it looks like ```$devVars``` might contain the csv string from the comments - i.e. ```"Azure:ServiceBus:Queue", "CS_AD_Entities_Connection_USR_PWD", …```.

Comment: @mclayton I am trying on my side. lets see how does it go.

Comment: @mclayton I am not a best powershell developer, but I got it working like Below, please review
 (`$devVars = az pipelines variable-group list -o json --group-name DEV --query "[0].variables | keys(@)" | ConvertFrom-Json | Sort-Object

Write-Host $devVars 

$devVars1 = $devVars -cmatch 'CS_|USR_|PWD_|LP_|PRT_|SB_|SP_|VAL_|URL_'

Write-Host $devVars1
(Compare-Object $devVars $devVars1).InputObject `)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its quality code, but I got it working like below

```
$devVars = az pipelines variable-group list -o json --group-name DEV --query "[0].variables | keys(@)" | ConvertFrom-Json | Sort-Object
Write-Host $devVars 
$devVars1 = $devVars -cmatch 'CS_|USR_|PWD_|LP_|PRT_|SB_|SP_|VAL_|URL_'
Write-Host $devVars1
(Compare-Object $devVars $devVars1).InputObject
```